# What does the echo() function do in this program?

Tags: c, tcp, echo

This is the description of the project I'm working on:

The
assignment requires you to write two programs (echoClient and
echoServer) to demonstrate communication between two processes
using TCP socket.
The echoServer program should take a port number (for example
6789) as the input:

```
$echoServer 6789
```

The echoClient program should take the server IP address (127.0.0.1)
and the server port as the input:

```
$echoClient 127.0.0.1 6789
```

The echoServer opens a socket and waits requests from the
user specified port.
(Make sure checking the bind result. You will very likely
have some programs by you or others occupied the port already).
When a connection is successfully setted up, the echoServer
read in what data from the socket, and echo it back by writing
"Echo: " where "input strings" are whatever
data the echo server reads in.
The echoClient once starts to run, it opens a socket to
connect to the echoServer. Once it connects to the server,
it sends a string to the server, and then reads from the
reply from the server, and print it out.
The echoServer program needs to be able support concurrent
requests. The basic structure of the server is provided as
following (you need to implement the echo function and the
parts of main function indicated by the comments.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>  

void echo (int sid, char *str);
int main (int argc, char **argv){
  int sockid, s;
  /* take in user specified port number from commandline argument */
  /* set up socket */
  int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//I added this
  while ((s=accept(sockid, ... ))>0) {
    if (fork()==0){
      /* Child process */
      read(s, buf ....);
      echo(s, buf);
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: What is the echo() function in the above program supposed to do?  And what are the steps to implement this function?

Comment: It would seem that, from the wording of the assignment, the `echo()` function is the bit you're supposed to write, and it should do the things that the assignment says it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows DOS programs "echo" is used to print a character or string to the console. I expect that's all this "echo" function does. It probably just prints a value to the console for user viewing. My guess is that if you went into the declaration of the echo() function, it would contain little more than a printf statement.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely makes sense.  The only other question I have is how do I get the socket address?